# Apply patterns on repeating operations

Tags: c#

What pattern/s can I apply on my code? I have been reading on the patterns *Bridge*, *Command*, and *Builder*, and it looks like I can apply them on the code block below, but I struggle at how I can apply them to my code. I've also tried adding a generic method, but I struggle with consuming it with my repository.

This is a webform backend code. I am using .Net 3.5 (can't upgrade), and C#7. Here is the code:

***Entities***
Note: I'm using data transfer objects because these classes have a lot of properties. Also, *SpecialRequestDTO* inherits *StandardRequestDTO*.

```
public class StandardRequest
{
   public int RequestType { get; protected set; }
   public string Name { get; protected set; }
   private StandardRequest(StandardRequestDTO dto) { Name = dto.Name; }
   public static StandardRequest Create(StandardRequestDTO dto) => new StandardRequest(dto);
}

public class SpecialRequest : StandardRequest
{
   public string Desc { get; protected set; }
   private SpecialRequest(SpecialRequestDTO dto) : base((StandardRequestDTO) dto) { Desc = dto.Desc; }
   public static SpecialRequest Create(SpecialRequestDTO dto) => new SpecialRequestDTO(dto);
}
```

***Repository***

```
public class Repository
{
    public void SaveStandardRequest(StandardRequest request)
    {
        var query = $"INSERT INTO Requests (Name, RequestType) Values(@{nameof(request.Name)}, @{nameof(request.RequestType)})";
        // sqlcommand code etc
    }

    public void SaveSpecialRequest(SpecialRequest request)
    {
       var query = $"INSERT INTO Requests (Name, RequestType, Desc) VALUES(@{nameof(request.Name)}, @{nameof(request.Name)}, @{nameof(request.Desc)})";
        // sqlcommand code etc
    }
}
```

***Index.aspx.cs***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (IsPostBack)
   {
       string requestTypeStr = Request.Form[nameof(requestTypeStr)];
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestTypeStr))
          return;
   }

   if (requestTypeStr == 0)
   {
       ValidateStandardRequestFields();
       var dto = CreateStandardRequestDTO();
       _repository.SaveStandardRequest(dto);
   }

   if (requestTypeStr == 1)
   {
       ValidateSpecialRequestFields();
       var dto = CreateSpecialRequestDTO();
       _repository.SaveSpecialRequest(dto);
   }
}
```

Comment: Patterns are solutions to specific problems. If you don't have those specific problems, you don't need those specific solutions. In this case, the problem is data access and *none* of those patterns apply. You can use a microORM like Dapper to execute parameterized SQL queries, or a full ORM like Entity Framework to get a Repository and UoW in the form of a DbContext. If you *really* need to map DTOs and view models, you can use AutoMapper

Comment: My problem is repeating operations, but are you saying that because I have a differing INSERT statements, my code cannot be trimmed down more? My worry is that if I get a new type of request, I have to change a lot of things on different places. Also, I am limited to using ADO.Net at the moment.

Comment: you could try using something like MagnaDB

Comment: Repository can be simplified to one method which handles both standard and special requests since they both go into the same table.   Just put a null in the Desc parameter if it is a standard request.

Comment: good point @stak. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took most of what I could from your post and this is what I could come up with.
Your DTO objects don't seem very clear to me, so I've left it out, but they have a role to play when it comes to saving the objects in the repository and I've left that part out.

Interface

```
    public interface IRequest
    {
        int RequestType { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        void ValidateFields();
    }
```

Two types of Request

```
    public class StandardRequest : IRequest
    {
        public int RequestType { get ; set ; }
        public string Name { get ; set; }

        public void ValidateFields()
        {
            //validation logic
        }
    }

    public class SpecialRequest:  IRequest
    {
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public int RequestType { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public void ValidateFields()
        {
            //validation logic
        }
    }
```

Factory to create the Request objects

```
    public class RequestFactory
    {
        public static IRequest CreateRequest(string requestTypeStr)
        {
            switch (requestTypeStr)
            {
                case "0": return new SpecialRequest();
                default: return new StandardRequest();
            }
        }
    }
```

Class to handle the interactions of the `IRequest` object, aptly named `RequestInteractions`, I know a poor name choice!

This class is what validates and saves the requests.

```
    public class RequestInteractions
    {
        private IRequest _requestObj;
        private Repository _repository;

        public RequestInteractions(IRequest requestObj, Repository repository)
        {
            _requestObj = requestObj;
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public bool ValidateAndSave()
        {
            try
            {
                _requestObj.ValidateFields();
                _repository.SaveRequest(_requestObj);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Repository - like I said, this needs to be fleshed out. The IRequest (through the DTO) should be able to tell you how it needs to be persisted. You'll have to fill this in.

```
    public class Repository
    {
        public void SaveRequest(IRequest requestObject)
        {
            //The respective DTO should help you figure out what to save based on the type of IRequest
        }
    }
```

Tying it all together

```
            var repository = new Repository();
            var requestObject = RequestFactory.CreateRequest("");
            var requestInteractions = new RequestInteractions(requestObject,repository);
            requestInteractions.ValidateAndSave();
```

> Benefit of this approach - You need to create a new Request class (and
>   a DTO) when you get a new Request to add to the system, the rest of
>   the plumbing need not be touched.
>
> Downside - Well, a lot of code compared to what you have.

Comment: This is awesome. I don't mind more code, because I am expecting more request types and it will bloat my original code. I'll study and implement, and see if it can be improved more. Thanks for taking your time on this one!